# How to get database values in combo_box?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, combobox, jcombobox

I am working on a small project which assigned to me by my teacher I am beginner to java
I have used combo box in my form to fetch data from database... I am able to get the data 
from the database while clicking on item1 in the combo box.. I want to get rid of item
so that i can get values directly here's my code...

```
import java.sql.*;
Statement stmt=null;
Connection con=null;
try
  {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:sql_login");
    stmt=con.createStatement();
    String search="select * from tblflight";
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(search);
    while(rs.next())
 {
    Date d1 = new Date(rs.getDate("departure_date").getTime());
        combo_box.addItem(d1);//
 }
        rs.close();
        con.close();
}catch(Exception e)
{
        e.printStackTrace();
}
 combox[ITEM1,ITEM2,ITEM3,ITEM4]//When form displays it shows these items
 but when I remove these items from properties I found combobox empty
 !![this is the first img when i open my form][1]
 ![this is the second img when i click any of the item][2]
```

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez5fa.png  "hidden"

![2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/orlDK.png "hidden"

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. From where you are removing the items?

Comment: Acutally item1,item2,item3 & item4 are by default values in properties of jcombobox when i remove those values from properties and i didn't insert any value into jcombobox properties it doesn't display anything...but when i left those items and i click any of them then I get values from database otherwise not

Comment: I want to show my column name in jcombox n when i open jcombox dropdown list I should get all of the values inside that column..
help would be more appreciated

Comment: you are not showing the declaration nor the creation of combo_box - that's probably your problem. Also, don't you want to add d1 to the combo rather than d_date (which is probably null and that may be your other problem)

Comment: go ahead look these pics might be you will get it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get selected value you can do it as follows,

```
String sSelectedValue = combobox.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

To get selected item index

```
int iSelectedItemIndex = combobox.getSelectedItemIndex();
```

To remove item.

```
combobox.removeItemAt(index); //index is the index of the item you want to remove from the list.
```